# Apache Camel File Transfer for previous interrupted process

Tags: file, apache-camel, interrupt, resume

I have two camel applications and their duty is to read files from the same directory, process them and send them to db consumer. To do this, my endpoint are like this:

```
file:/data/air?preMove=thread&amp;readLock=fileLock &amp;idempotent=true&amp;idempotentRepository=#fileStore&amp;include=AIROUTPUTCDR_(.*).AIR.gz&amp;move=/data/air/success&amp;moveFailed=error
```

As u can see, application polls file from polldir based on filters, move them under thread dir to read, read the file and move to success folder.

But with this flow, if I kill an application and start it again, the files ,which were being processed, will not be processed because they are under threads folder.

My question is, is there a way to resume reading the files which are just interrupted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No if you do a hard kill on the application while a file was pre moved, then you would neeed manually to move these files from pre move, back into the source folder, so they can be picked up again

Comment: It would be good to have a functionality to check the folder structure which has been given in the endpoint url to organise the files and the structure. Is there any "onStartup" kind of listeners to make this manually in xml config?

Comment: If you use spring xml then just define a <bean> and have it call any method on the bean on startup, then you can move the files back manually etc. Is the threads folder by any chance local only, eg its not a shared folder?

Comment: It is a shared folder. I could do the process that u mentioned but I am looking for a cleaner version. But it seems , I ll do the one above. Thanks Claus